# flutter hot reload button in vscode doesn't make effect

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I have a small problem with vscode.
In the flutter I cannot use the hot reload button in the debug toolbar.
the only way for hot reloading is pressing "ctrl + s" (save project) .
is there any way to fix this button ?
i dont have this problem in android studio. i can use hot reload button in this IDE .

Comment: I had always problem with VScode.. I only use Android Studio now.. I recommend to use it

Answer (score 0):

This is because Android Studio has **Auto Save** enabled by default, while VS Code doesn't.

To activate it : **File -> Auto Save**